# Looking for Toldos Yeshu (1705 version). Does anyone have?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, christianity, tannaim

I'm researching the story that the Christian Apostle Simon -- later Saint Peter -- was actually a Jewish plant who was instructed by the rabbis to change Christian observances and beliefs to make it much more distinguishable from rabbinic Judaism.  Dr. Shnayer Leiman, of YU, mentions a 1705 un-censored version of Toldos Yeshu as a prime source for this.  Does anyone know where I can find it?

Comment: Sha'ul/Paul would be a far more credible candidate for such a role

Comment: @Henry:  True, Henry, but the sources seem to say it was Simon/Peter.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/650/603

Comment: See the footnote in the vagshal moznayim shas in Avoda Zara 10a.

Answer (score 7):

You can try this pdf of its text: http://lemidrash.free.fr/JudaismeChristianisme/huldreich.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Here is [Huldreich's 1705 edition](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=05JAAAAAcAAJ), with the Latin translation. It can be downloaded for free.

The standard critical edition used for many years [Das Leben Jesu nach Jüdischen Quellen](https://archive.org/details/daslebenjesunac00kraugoog). The 1705 Huldreich edition is discussed with a critical apparatus among the other traditions. It was found that several MSS of the Huldrich edition exist that predate 1705.

A critical edition was recently published in two volumes ([here](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=81hHsItgjqIC) and [here](https://books.google.co.il/books/about/Toledot_Yeshu.html?id=XTZMrgEACAAJ&redir_esc=y)) by Meerson and Schäfer. These are very surely very relevant to your research.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Sefer called "Otzer HaMedreshim" (I know it's rather "general" but that's what it's called!) that I once saw that brings down the story about Shimon HaKeifeh (also known by different names) who is the one that you are referring to (based on Dr. Leiman's article on this issue and the sources cited there -- The Baruch Tam being probably the main and best known source for this in halachic seforim (however there is at least one more as Dr. Leiman brings down.)

The article for those that are interested in this fascinating analysis of Tes Teves and the history behind it, together with the story the questioner is referring to can see it [here](http://www.leimanlibrary.com/texts_of_publications/36.%20The%20Scroll%20of%20Fasts%20The%20Ninth%20of%20Tebeth.pdf).

Comment: That's excellent - thank you! On p176, where it appears to quote a section of this text, it cites the source as being ספר הלכות גדולות. Is that a typo? Why is it citing the Semag?

Comment: ספר הלכות גדולות = בה"ג

Comment: Sorry, I meant Bahag, not Semag. Shouldn't the citation be to the MTB?

Answer (score 2):

here are some texts to start with

http://www.bitethewaxtadpole.org/ninth.htm

http://www.bitethewaxtadpole.org/frenkel.jpg  (tav kuf pey)

http://www.bitethewaxtadpole.org/simon%20peter.htm

http://www.geocities.ws/ffbrosends/

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of different editions, non are canonical

http://archive.org/stream/sefertoledotyes00unkngoog#page/n5/mode/2up

http://www.essene.com/History&Essenes/toled.htm