# Where did Rabbeinu Tam attribute Nishmas to Peter?

Tags: prayer-book, christianity, rishonim

Lots of sources (eg [this one](https://www.kotzkblog.com/2016/11/102-did-st-peter-compose-nishmat-prayer.html?m=1)) say that Rabbeinu Tam attributed the prayer Nishmas Kol Chai to the apostle Peter. But no one seems to give a precise citation of where Rabbeinu Tam said this. Can anyone here help?

Comment: I don’t think you’re going to be successful in finding a source here. Rabbeinu Tam is quoted as attributing the piyut Eten Tehillah to Peter. The attribution of Nishmat to Peter is recorded in the name of R Yehuda ben Yaakov.

Comment: @JoelK Indeed, though so many sources say that he attributed Nishmas to Peter that I wonder if they can all be wrong. Meanwhile though if you can help me find where he did it for Esein Tehillah that would be very good too!

Comment: וחותם בנשמת כל חי. דנשמת כל חי היא ברכת השיר. ששנינו בערבי פסחים. ויש שאומרי' על אותו (כבל) [נבל] שמעון פטר חמור שהיא טעות של (דומה) [רומה] יסדו (עם אותו תחילה) [אותה תפילה]. ושאר תפילות כשהיה על הסלע. וחס ושלום שלא תהיה זאת בישר'. (ולכל האומות דיבר) [וכל האומר דבר] זה. כשיבנה בית המקדש (יביאו) [יביא] חטאת (שמצה) [שמנה]:  https://www.sefaria.org/Machzor_Vitry,_Laws_of_Pesach_66.2

Comment: **ורבינו יעקב בר' מאיר** פוסק. דבכל י"ח ברכות יכול אדם לחדש בין דברים שהן הודאה ותפילה. בין דברים שהן צרכיו. הואיל ומעין ברכה הוא מחדש. ולא הוי הפסק ברכה כלל. ומותר להאריך בהן כעין קרובות תפילות וסליחות שמסרו לנו רבותי' אנשי השם. **מימות שמעון כיפה שיסד סדר של יום הכיפורים. אתן תהלה**.
 https://www.sefaria.org.il/Machzor_Vitry%2C_Laws_of_Rosh_HaShanah.325.1?lang=he

Comment: While we’re on the topic, I remember hearing a rabbi say that there’s some halacha book that when regarding why we fast on 10 tevet it says “for reasons we can’t make clear” or something like that and this is a reference to Peter’s yahrtzeit. Does anyone know which halacha book this is in?

Comment: @CuriousYid start with resources here https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23123/looking-for-toldos-yeshu-1705-version-does-anyone-have

Comment: @rosends that answered my question thanks!